# Falt error while fatching data from the server to android app

Tags: php, android

I had return a code to fetch data from the server to android app in php. I am creating and array that will bring all the table name it column details and all the data in the table.But when i run the php code in browser to check the data in echo json form its showing this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10859044 bytes) in C:\dev\workspaceneerav\crmandroid\JSON.php on line 391
```

here is the php code for fetching the data from table and storing it in array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultsListTables))
{

$temporarydata = array();
$TableName = new ArrayObject();
$getTabledetails = 'show columns from '.$row[0].'';
$resultdetails = mysql_query($getTabledetails);
$TableName['tablename'] = $row[0];
$column = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultdetails))
{
    $column_list =new ArrayObject();
    $column_list['FieldName'] = $rows['Field'];
        $column_list['Default'] = $rows['Default'];
        if(strpos($rows['Type'],'(') == false)
        {
            $column_list['dataType'] = $rows['Type'];
            $column_list['dataType_limit'] ='';
        }else
        {
            $type = explode('(',$rows['Type']);
            $column_list['dataType'] = $type[0];
            $column_list['dataType_limit'] = '('.$type[1];
        }


    $column_list['Extra'] = $rows['Extra'];
    $column_list['Null_value'] = $rows['Null'];
    $column_list['Key_value'] = $rows['Key'];
     $column[] = $column_list;
}

 $TableName['column_details'] = $column;
 $Tabledetails[]=$TableName;
 $select_table = "select * from ".$row[0]."";
$resultTableData = mysql_query($select_table);
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultTableData))
 {
    $temporarydata[] = $row1;
 }
    $data[$row[0]] = $temporarydata;

}
```

Can any one tell where the error is.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.